# <kbd> tags in headings are too small

Tags: feature-request, design, markdown, kbd

The styling for the `<kbd>` tags is, as we all know, quite nice: <kbd>Enter</kbd>, e.g.
However, these are too small in headings:

> ## Saving files with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
>
> Body text, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> again.

Note that the tags are the same size as in the body text, just bold.
Inline code is handled better:

> ## Saving files with `Ctrl-S`
>
> Body text, with `Ctrl-S` again.

Here, the `Ctrl-S` looks more in line with its location (it's the right size), but of course inline code isn't the right tool for the job here.

The desired behavior would be something like this:

[image: Desired behavior of <code><kbd></code> tags in headers]

I used `font-size: 16px;` here; adjust to taste.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved with the following style rule:

```
kbd {
    font-size: 75% !important;
}
```

The `!important` is only needed to override the current `font-size: 11px` rule, and wouldn't be necessary if the original rule were to be revised.

(At first I tried removing the `font-size: 11px` rule entirely, but it was obviously put there for a reason, since normal-font-size `<kbd>` tags look terrible. `75%` has the same, desired effect but doesn't use a constant value, so it works in headings too.)

Calling @IlmariKaronen to add this to SOUP. :)

Comment: I'm back from vacation and doing SOUPy stuff again. Added to v1.29 devel branch, with credit to you. Thanks! (I did tweak the font size up slightly to 80%, which gives a calculated size of 11.2px for body text, and exactly 16px for level 1 headings.)

Comment: Ps. An interesting side effect of this change is that it makes [nested <kbd> tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114743) *much* less intrusive.